# Adding another var to URL of get request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am having an issue finding an answer to this, currently below is my get request, currently I have one variable "tii", I need to add another variable to put as the URL IP, how can I add another variable? If I add it with tii I do not understand how to specify which var you want placed where.

```
group_1_a_source = requests.get("http://100.104.35.16/slot/6//htdocs/v.api/apis/EV/GET/parameters/960.0.%s" % tii)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a strings question to me. You can use fstrings:

```
a = 1
b = 'hello'
c = f'{b} there sir. The number is {a}'
print(c)
>>> hello there sir. The number is 1
```

In your case it would be:

```
r = f"http://100.104.35.16/slot/6//htdocs/v.api/apis/EV/GET/parameters/960.0.{tii}.{other_variable}" # or however else you need to format it
group_1_a_source = requests.get(r)
```

Or something similar

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's `f-string` functionality to achieve that. For example, you could write—

```py
variable_1 = "foo"
variable_2 = "bar"

group_1_a_source = requests.get(f"http://100.104.35.16/slot/6//htdocs/v.api/apis/EV/GET/parameters/960.0.{variable_1}.{variable_2}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either `f string` or concatenation. I havent tried concatenation for urls yet but explore it. If you want a quick solution just use an f string I always use it in case of urls.